# Complex inheritance variable merge

Tags: php

Problem:
I want to merge `n depth` class `array variable` into one, ex classes:

`abstract class A extends -> class B extends -> class C extends -> N`.

The problem lies that each class has the same variable `$codes` that has `different result`, and in `best case` we need that `abstract class A` would be able to merge each class variable into one.

I fully understand how PHP inheritance works and what are the limitations.

I am asking, if you have any bright ideas or a bit different solutions that may solve this problem:

```
abstract class A extends Exception
{
   /**
   * Variable holds codes
   *
   * @var array $codes
   */
  protected static $codes = [
      400001 => 'bad_request',
      404001 => 'not_found',
      409001 => 'conflict',
      429001 => 'too_many_requests',
      500001 => 'internal_server_error',
      503001 => 'service_unavailable'
  ];

  /**
   * Inherit error codes array, so that other child classes could use them.
   */
  public static function getInheritanceCodes(): array
  {
    if(static::$codes) {
        $classA = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);
        static::$codes = $classA['codes'] + static::$codes;
    }
    return static::$codes;
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class B extends A
{
   /**
   * Variable holds codes
   *
   * @var array $codes
   */
    protected static $codes = [
        400007 => 'range_too_large',
        400008 => 'invalid_token',
        400009 => 'bad_format',
        409002 => 'already_exists'
    ];
}
```

Child:

```
class C extends B
{
   /**
   * Variable holds codes
   *
   * @var array $codes
   */
    protected static $codes = [
        400004 => 'can_not_be_moved',
        400001 => 'invalid_request',
    ];
}
```

...

```
// by creating child object
$result = C::getInheritanceCodes();
print_r($result);
exit;
```

Current result:

```
array:7 [
  400001 => "bad_request"
  404001 => "not_found"
  409001 => "conflict"
  429001 => "too_many_requests"
  500001 => "internal_server_error"
  503001 => "service_unavailable"
  400004 => "can_not_be_moved"
]
```

Expected result:

```
array:11 [
  400001 => "bad_request"
  404001 => "not_found"
  409001 => "conflict"
  429001 => "too_many_requests"
  500001 => "internal_server_error"
  503001 => "service_unavailable"
  400004 => "can_not_be_moved"
  400007 => "range_too_large"
  400008 => "invalid_token"
  400009 => "bad_format"    
  409002 => "already_exists"   
]
```

If you believe that current code design is incorrect, please give your suggestions.

Thank you for your time,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Inherit error codes array, so that other child classes could use them.
 * @param string|null $class
 */
private static function inheritErrorCodes(?string $class = null): void
{
    // Get parent class
    $class = get_parent_class($class ?? static::class);

    // Check, if parent contains variable
    if (!empty($class) && isset($class::$errorCodes)) {
        // Inherit error codes
        static::$errorCodes += $class::$errorCodes;

        // Recursive call parent class
        self::inheritErrorCodes($class);
    }
}
```

This solution will set static::$codes variable with full inheritance. :)